# SQL Server duplicating results three times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to filter my results to output the names of people who work on all projects controlled controlled by department 5. I thought what I wrote below would give me the desired result, but instead it displays the names of the people who work on those project three times each. What would I do to remedy this?

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Minit, e.Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e, DEPARTMENT as d, PROJECT as p
WHERE p.Dnum=d.Dnumber AND d.Dnumber=e.Dno AND p.Dnum=5
```

Which results in the output:

```
John    B   Smith
John    B   Smith
John    B   Smith
Franklin    T   Wong
Franklin    T   Wong
Franklin    T   Wong
Joyce   A   English
Joyce   A   English
Joyce   A   English
Ramesh  K   Narayan
Ramesh  K   Narayan
Ramesh  K   Narayan
```

Comment: You should really stop use old style comma joins and move to using the correct joins.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You'd need to provide some sample data and expected results so we can see why the results are duplicating - we don't know your data structure.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: There is no where condition specified on project table to identify which department they worked on ..I don't know if that table is needed anywhere

Comment: Output: https://i.imgur.com/LXc9NBc.png desired result: the names are listed only once

Comment: Yes @howimetmyself , that is a image of the result your query gives you. But now you should add that result in your question by editing your question and add it as a text not as an image. Also, add the data from which you get this results ? You do not need to write 10 rows of data for every table, only two or three will be enough to represent your problem... And finally  please do not add image, add text.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a many to one relationship and aren't taking that into account when performing your ANSI-89 (that's for 1989) joins. As a result you get multiple rows per Employee, due to the multiple rows joined in the tables `DEPARTMENT` and `PROJECT`.

Considering that you only reference `EMPLOYEE` in the `SELECT` I *assume* you actually want an `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.Fname,
       e.Minit,
       e.Lname
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.Dno = 5 --Inferred as p.Dnum=5 and p.Dnum=d.Dnumber and d.Dnumber=e.Dno. Thus e.Dno = 5
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.DEPARTMENT D
                   JOIN dbo.PROJECT P ON D.Dnumber = P.Dnum
              WHERE D.Dnumber = E.Dno);
```

If, however, you don't care if the Employee has a department (or project) then the following would be fine:

```
SELECT e.Fname,
       e.Minit,
       e.Lname
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.Dno = 5;
```